# Pygame doesn't change my sprite accordingly to my character attributes

Tags: pygame

I'm trying to get my character to change images once it reaches a certain distance from another character. Basically, if the character is 50 or more units away, she is set to walking mode, but if she is less than 50 units away, she is set to attack mode, which have their corresponding images/powersets.

I've tried while loops and adding other conditions

```
if sif.x - cap.x > 50 and sif.collideCount == 0:
    sif.moveLeft() #cap is the other character
elif cap.x - sif.x > 50 and sif.collideCount == 0:
    sif.moveRight()
elif cap.x - sif.x <= 50 and sif.collideCount == 0:
    sif.punch = True
    sif.right = True
    sif.punchRight()
    if sif.rect.colliderect(cap.rect):
        sif.collideCount = 1
        sif.collided = True
if sif.collided:
    sif.moveLeft()
    if sif.x < 30:
        sif.moveRight()
        sif.collideCount = 0
        sif.collided = False
```

## punch function

```
def punchRight(self):
    self.img = pygame.image.load('sifpunch.png')
    self.punch = True
    self.right = True
    self.left = False
    self.x += self.vel
    self.rect.x = self.x
    screen.blit(self.img, (self.x,self.y))
```

## draw function that contains the updated image:

```
def draw(self, screen):
        elif self.punch and self.right:
            self.img = pygame.image.load('sifpunch.png')
            screen.blit(self.img, (self.x,self.y))
```

Pygame never ends up setting sif.punch to True, so Sif continues walking to the left and right instead of switching to attack mode.

Comment: did you run it in terminal/console/cmd.exe to see error messages ? You have error in `draw()` - you can't use `elif` without `if` - and you should see error message.

Comment: in `punchRight` you should assing new image but you should blit it only in `draw`

Comment: inside `punchRight` you set `self.punch` and `self.right` so you don't have to do it in `elif cap.x - sif.x <= 50 and sif.collideCount == 0: sif.punch = True  sif.right = True`

Comment: I can't run code to see how it works but you can put `print()` in many different places to display values in variables and display info like "I'm in 'for' loop" to see what values you have in variables and which part of code is executed. This way you can see if code do what you expecte.

Comment: @furas there was more code in draw that i didn't include here! i had conditions for self.left only, self.left and self.punch, and self.right only as well.

Comment: @furas also i have been putting print statements to debug. self.punch is initialized as true inside the if statement, but outside of the if statement it goes back to being false

Comment: put `print()` in all places where you have `self.punch  = False` to see when it is set `False`. Probably after `sif.punchRight()` code runs other function which set it `False` back. Maybe one of your `if/else` doesn't work as you expect. Put `print()` in all `if/else` to see which one is executed.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out - I changed the boundary from 50 to 200. A 50 unit range was too small for the clip to show up in time.